# ThreadPoolExecutor or not

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-service

I am using a service to run a number of threads. So inside `onStartCommand`, I simply create a runnable with the appropriate work to be done and then I pass the runnable to a thread as

```
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Is there any problem with doing things this way versus using a ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: theoretically no. Consider looking into Handlers

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763835/new-threadtask-start-vs-threadpoolexecutor-submittask-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

you don't have any means to stop the running thread but if you have `ThreadPoolExceutor` instance, then you can shut down it and hence stop all the running worker threads associated with the thread pool.